# Set colour and alpha separately for positive and negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a scatter plot with points coloured by their log2 value in the following data:

```
   chromosome start   end test  ref position        log2      p.value cnv cnv.size cnv.log2 cnv.p.value
1           X     1 10000   50   74     5000 -0.29260198 2.857792e-06   0       NA       NA          NA
2           X  5001 15000   50   72    10000 -0.25307362 4.125984e-05   0       NA       NA          NA
10          X 45001 55000  992 1043    50000  0.20066806 7.482412e-04   0       NA       NA          NA
11          X 50001 60000 1287 1417    55000  0.13416749 1.687005e-02   0       NA       NA          NA
12          X 55001 65000  892 1149    60000 -0.09226799 7.342756e-02   0       NA       NA          NA
13          X 60001 70000  651  838    65000 -0.09129751 7.556642e-02   0       NA       NA          NA
```

I'm trying to colour by log2 values where:

- higer positive values are dark blue and solid
- lower positive values are light blue and more transparent
- values in range -0.75:0.75 are white
- lower negative values are light red and more transparent
- higher negative values are dark red and solid

I've tried to achieve this by plotting the pos and neg values separately:

```
pos<-subset(clean_file, clean_file$log2 > 0)
neg<-subset(clean_file, clean_file$log2 < 0)

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data=pos, aes(x = start, y = log2, alpha = log2, colour = log2))
p <- p + scale_colour_gradient2(low=muted("blue"), high=muted("green"), limits=c(0, 0.75), na.value="black" )   
p <- p + geom_point(data=neg, aes(x = start, y = log2, alpha = -log2, colour = -log2))
p <- p + scale_colour_gradient2(low=muted("purple"), high=muted("red"), limits=c(0, -0.75), na.value="darkred" )
p <- p + ylim(-5,5)
p <- p + facet_wrap(~chromosome, scale="free_x")
```

But the result is not right (and I get the following error):

> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for
>   'colour', which will replace the existing scale.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically achieves what I want:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

cols <- brewer.pal(n = 5, name = "RdBu")

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data=clean_file, aes(x = start, y = log2, colour = log2), size = 1)
p <- p + ylim(-5,5)
p <- p + scale_colour_gradientn(colours = cols, 
    values = rescale(c(-2, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 2)),
    guide = "colorbar", limits=c(-5, 5))      
p <- p + facet_wrap(~chromosome, scale="free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per the help file for `scale_colour_gradientn()`:

"if colours should not be evenly positioned along the gradient this vector gives the position (between 0 and 1) for each colour in the colours vector. See rescale for a convience function to map an arbitrary range to between 0 and 1."

So you would need to make some adjustments. One approach would be to create an additional variable, re-scaling log2:

```
clean_file$log2_scale <- scales::rescale(clean_file$log2)
```

Then make a note of what the equivalent log2_scale values are for log2 values that you want to colour by. Then replace the vector in the values argument with the log2_scale values that you have chosen (these should be between 0 and 1).

Finally, you will need to add the mapping into your ggplot aesthetics:

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data=clean_file, aes(x = start, y = log2, colour = log2))
p <- p + ylim(-5,5)
p <- p + scale_colour_gradientn(
  colours = c( "red", "yellow", "white", "lightblue", "darkblue" ),
  values = scales::rescale(c( 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1))
```

To automate the calculation of the values vector, you could create a custom function that uses the clean_file data.frame and maps the original log2 values to the scaled values.